# How to find a model from a collection according to some attribute other than the ID?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I have a model with several object:

```
//Model
Friend = Backbone.Model.extend({
    //Create a model to hold friend attribute
    name: null,
}); 

//objects
var f1 = new Friend({ name: "Lee" });
var f2 = new Friend({ name: "David"});
var f3 = new Friend({ name: "Lynn"});
```

and also, I will add these friends object to a collection:

```
//Collection
Friends = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Friend,
});

Friends.add(f1);
Friends.add(f2);
Friends.add(f3);
```

and now I want to get a model according to the name of the Friend. I know that I can add an `ID` attribute to achieve this. But I think there should have some more simple way to do this.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Backbone collections support the underscorejs `find` method, so using that should work.

```
things.find(function(model) { return model.get('name') === 'Lee'; });
```

Comment: so the find function will return the model when the callback function's return value is true?

Answer (score 87):

For simple attribute based searches you can use [`Collection#where`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-where):

> **where** `collection.where(attributes)`
>
> Return an array of all the models in a collection that match the passed **attributes**. Useful for simple cases of `filter`.

So if `friends` is your `Friends` instance, then:

```
var lees = friends.where({ name: 'Lee' });
```

There's also [`Collection#findWhere`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-findWhere) (a later addition as noted in the comments):

> **findWhere** `collection.findWhere(attributes)`
>
> Just like *where*, but directly returns only the first model in the collection that matches the passed **attributes**.

so if you're only after one then you can say things like:

```
var lee = friends.findWhere({ name: 'Lee' });
```

Comment: Simplicity at its best!

Comment: Alternatively using `friends.findWhere({name: "Lee"})` should get you only the first model in the collection that matches (thus effectively saving you an `[0]`), I suspect however that it requires Backbone >1.0.0

Comment: I always strive to use the tools as they were intended to be used... this is the Backbone way!

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way is to use "idAttribute" option of Backbone Model to let Backbone know the that you want to use "name" as your Model Id.

```
 Friend = Backbone.Model.extend({
      //Create a model to hold friend attribute
      name: null,
      idAttribute: 'name'
 });
```

Now you can directly use Collection.get() method to retrieve a friend using his name. This way Backbone does not loop through all of your Friend models in the Collection but can directly fetch a model based on its "name".

```
var lee = friends.get('Lee');
```

Answer (score 5):

You can call `findWhere()` on Backbone collections, that will return exactly the model you are looking for.

Example:

```
var lee = friends.findWhere({ name: 'Lee' });
```